# How can I get Tabular to only work with certain lines and to use spaces as a delimiter?

Tags: regular-expression, alignment, plugin-tabular

How can I get Tabular.vim to only consider and affect lines that match `/^item\s/`, to use `/\s\+/` as the delimiter, to left-align everything, and to use at least three spaces between words?

For example:

```
thing      ...
item Aaaaaaaaaaaaa "aaa"                    Bbb
  aaa             ...
  ...
item    Aaaa "aaaa"  Bbb
  ...
  ...


item   Aaa    "aaa" Bbb
  ...
  ...
```

should change to:

```
thing      ...
item   Aaaaaaaaaaaaa   "aaa"    Bbb
  aaa             ...
  ...
item   Aaaa            "aaaa"   Bbb
  ...
  ...


item   Aaa             "aaa"    Bbb
  ...
  ...
```

I've been trying to use `AddTabularPipeline` without success and with much confusion, and I'd like to throw my attempts out and figure out how the solutions here work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Plugin EasyAlign](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align)

by Junegunn

I tried to give you an answer for *Tabular.vim*. However, I could only figure it out how to do it with vim-easy-align:

```
:%EasyAlign */\s\+/g/item\s/
```

I have used the shorthand notation for the `filter` option for the command [`:EasyAlign`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align#easyalign-command). The non-shorthand version looks like `:%EasyAlign */\s\+/ { 'filter': 'g/item\s/'}`.
More details about the filter option can be found [here](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align#filtering-lines) and under `:h easy-align-filtering-lines`.

Vim-easy-align provides a second way to use it, called the interactive mode:

```
<Visual mode>ga*<CTRL-F>g/\item\s/<CR><Space>                " visual mode
ga<Text Object or Motion>*<CTRL-F>g/\item\s/<CR><Space>      " operator mode
```

I am not entirely convinced the interactive mode is here more intuitive or easier to use.

I was hoping to use IMHO the more naive approach `:g/item\s/EasyAlign */\s\+/<CR>` but this does not work as well similar to *Tabular.vim*.

Note your question has been raised on stackoverflow and on the issue tracker of *Tabular.vim*:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6797837/vim-tabularize-how-to-ignore-lines-containing-curly-braces
- https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/issues/10

There seems to be the undocumented function `:GTabularize /pattern[/format]` which, however, does not exactly do what you want. But was added to *Tabular.vim* after someone raised the wish to combine `:global` with `:Tabularize`.

Another vim alignment plugin is [vim-lion](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lion) which cannot help you here either.

#### `:global` applies `[cmd]` on each marked line separately

If I read `:h :global` correctly, the naive expectation, all filtered lines are provided for `[cmd]`, is not true! I think this should be learned from this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation of EasyAlign and the excellent example code. I've also found that the number of spaces at the narrowest width is configurable by using `*\l0l0l2` in place of `*/\s\+/`. Change the `2` to one *less* than how many spaces you want (*e*. *g*., if you want six spaces at the narrowest point, change it to `5`).